# Java function for Encrypt/Decrypt like Mysql's AES_ENCRYPT and AES_DECRYPT

Tags: java, mysql, aes

Is there any way to get the same result as doing in MySQL

```
SELECT AES_ENCRYPT("text", "key")
```

using a Java function?

And if possible, what's the other function to simulate the AES_DECRYPT.

Comment: Dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/992019/java-256bit-aes-encryption

Answer (score 4):

Ok, I've managed to get it working like this.

MySQL Query:

```
SELECT HEX(aes_encrypt("password", "0123456789012345"));
```

Java function:

```
public static String aes_encrypt(String password, String strKey) {
    try {
        byte[] keyBytes = Arrays.copyOf(strKey.getBytes("ASCII"), 16);

        SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);

        byte[] cleartext = password.getBytes("UTF-8");
        byte[] ciphertextBytes = cipher.doFinal(cleartext);

        return new String(Hex.encodeHex(ciphertextBytes));

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } return null;
}
```

Comment: Please, please, please get rid of this ugly error handling. And don't use printStackTrace(), ever. Either rethrow the exception, or use logging (either JDK or 3rd party). If you're not going to handle the errors in any useful way, just try { ... some code ... } catch(Exception e) { throw new RuntimeException(e); }. At the moment, if an error occurs, a stack trace will print somewhere (maybe, depending on what platform you're on), and then your code will proceed as if nothing went wrong.

Comment: Probably also worth pointing out that that Hex class is from Apache Commons:  http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Hex.html

Comment: any one have equivalent java implemetation for Mysql AES CBC-256 implementation

Comment: Dear infinito, I have 2 notes: 1)you switch the password with text in mysql and java code, 2) you can use the UTF-8 instead of ASCII -> should be SELECT HEX(aes_encrypt("0123456789012345","password"));
byte[] keyBytes = Arrays.copyOf(password.getBytes("UTF-8"/*"ASCII"*/), 16); .....
byte[] cleartext = strKey.getBytes("UTF-8");

Answer (score 4):

If you need the code to decrypt the algorithm is here JAVA

```
 public static String aes_decrypt(String passwordhex, String strKey) throws Exception {
    try {
        byte[] keyBytes = Arrays.copyOf(strKey.getBytes("ASCII"), 16);

        SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
        Cipher decipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");

        decipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);

        char[] cleartext = passwordhex.toCharArray();

        byte[] decodeHex = Hex.decodeHex(cleartext);

        byte[] ciphertextBytes = decipher.doFinal(decodeHex);

        return new String(ciphertextBytes);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getMessage();
    }
    return null;
}
```

It received a standard hex format string but variable and returns the password. Test with those in main method

```
    System.out.println(aes_encrypt("your_string_password", "your_string_key"));
    System.out.println(aes_decrypt("standard_hex_format_string ", "your_string_key"));
```

firstable test only with encrypt, then just with decrypt. 
By the way you must install 'commons-codec-1.6.jar' so you can use the Hex class
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/download_codec.cgi

Greetings from Ecuador, Ibarra

Answer (score 0):

in my case i just code like this

```
 private static final char[] HEX_ARRAY = "0123456789ABCDEF".toCharArray();
    public static String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
    char[] hexChars = new char[bytes.length * 2];
    for (int j = 0; j < bytes.length; j++) {
        int v = bytes[j] & 0xFF;
        hexChars[j * 2] = HEX_ARRAY[v >>> 4];
        hexChars[j * 2 + 1] = HEX_ARRAY[v & 0x0F];
    }
    return new String(hexChars);
 }
```

and than create method aes 128

```
public static String aes_encrypt(String password, String strKey) {
        try {
            byte[] keyBytes = Arrays.copyOf(strKey.getBytes("ASCII"), 16);

            SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);

            byte[] cleartext = password.getBytes("UTF-8");
            byte[] ciphertextBytes = cipher.doFinal(cleartext);

            return new String(bytesToHex(ciphertextBytes));

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        return null;
}
```

example :
mysql code

```
SELECT HEX(aes_encrypt("text", "0123456889812345"))
```

java code

```
System.out.println(aes_encrypt("text", "0123456889812345"));
```